# Error - Mongo restore from version 2.4 to 3.6.5

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I have dumped a database from a server using `mongodump` - the version of mongodb used here is `2.4`.

To restore the dump into the latest `3.6.5` mongoDb instance I used the command `mongorestore --drop -d database dumpFolder`

I got the error:
`Failed: myDb.collectx: error creating collection myDb.collectx: error running create command: BSON field 'OperationSessionInfo.create' is a duplicate field`

Answer (score 2):

I'm hitting the same thing, and found some detail in an answer on a related site: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/201827/failed-to-import-a-mongodb-database-with-duplicate-fields

What I've gathered is that mongodump version 2.2 and later is incompatible with earlier versions of MongoD - so check the version you used to dump the data.

I was able to use `bsondump my_collection.bson` to get a JSON dump output of the details, so I suspect I can load it from that, even though it's not recommended.

**UPDATE:**

I was able to use `bsondump` and `mongoimport` together with the raw BSON file to get the data loaded:

```
bsondump my_collection.bson > my_collection.json
mongoimport -d my_db -c my_collection my_collection.json
```

So a tad inelegant, but I was able to load up the MongoDB 2.4 data into a MongoDB 3.6.5 instance locally.